# VBS: Jump between directories

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write one small vb script where I faced with the problem of jumping between directories. Exampe:

```
dim devenv
set devenv = objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("VS120COMNTOOLS") + "..\IDE\devenv.com"
```

My problem is that vb doesn't understand '..\' or I use it incorrectly. How to jump between directories correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who you want to jump, but this shows how to set the .CurrentDirectory based on an environment variable (and how to to string concatenation correctly):

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim goWS : Set goWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Echo 0, goWS.CurrentDirectory
WScript.Echo 1, goFS.FileExists("devenv.com")
'Dim sPath : sPath = goWS.Environment("PROCESS").Item("VS90COMNTOOLS") & "..\IDE"
Dim sPath : sPath = goFS.BuildPath(goWS.Environment("PROCESS").Item("VS90COMNTOOLS"), "..\IDE")
WScript.Echo 2, sPath
goWS.CurrentDirectory = sPath
WScript.Echo 3, goFS.FileExists("devenv.com")
```

output:

```
cscript 27444871.vbs
0 E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\27276693\vbs
1 0
2 C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\..\IDE
3 -1
```

Using .BuildPath instead of string concatenation is advisable.

**P.S.**

Just saw: Your

```
set devenv = objShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("VS120COMNTOOLS") + "..\IDE\devenv.com"
```

tries to use `Set` for non-object/string assignment.